# Separating in even and odd powers if they don't commute

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, noncommutative-algebra, quantum-groups

During a lesson on Rabi's oscillations, my professor computed the following series:
$$H = \sum_n \left( (a |e_1 \rangle \langle e_0| + a^\dagger |e_0 \rangle \langle e_1|\right)^n$$
separating in odd and even cases. Where $e_0$, $e_1$ are a basis and $a$, $a^\dagger$ are the creation and annihilation operators acting on the fock states.

The even series is:
$$H^{2n} = (a^{\dagger} a)^n |e_0\rangle \langle e_0| + (a a^\dagger )^n |e_1\rangle \langle e_1|$$
While to compute the odd one, he multiplied to the left for one term of the series. But, I noticed that the result changes if you multiply to the right or to the left, in fact:
$$H^{1+2n} = a |e_1\rangle \langle e_0| (a^\dagger a)^n + a^\dagger |e_0 \rangle \langle e_1 |(a a^\dagger)^n$$
$$H^{2n+1} =  |e_1\rangle \langle e_0| (a a^\dagger )^n a +  |e_0 \rangle \langle e_1 |(a^\dagger a)^n a^\dagger$$
Why do I get two different results? They should commute, but I can't get the same result using the commutator between $a$ and $a^\dagger$.

Answer (score 1):

You find the same answer, of course, by virtue of the basic maneuver of such operators,
$$
a a^\dagger = a^\dagger a+1\equiv N+1,
$$
and
$$
f(N) a =a f(N-1), \\
f(N) a^\dagger = f(N+1)  a^\dagger,
$$
∴
$$
a N^n= (N+1)^n a ,\\
a^\dagger (N+1)^n= N^n a^\dagger.
$$

The creation and annihilation operator functions commute with the extraneous basis states, since the Fock space does.